# How to remove an object from a list in another class? c#

Tags: c#, xna

I want to add an health bar to my 2d platformer but I can't get the health to remove from the bar..

This is what I was trying so far in my rocket class:

```
public void CheckPlayerCollision()
{
    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    Health health = new Health(3, "Sprites/spr_health");

    if (this.CollidesWith(player) && this.Visible)
        foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
        {
            SpriteGameObject h = obj as SpriteGameObject;
            {
                gameObjects.Remove(h);
            }
        }
}
```

The hitdetection works and I can get health to reduce in the health class without using both the rocket and the player --> see 2nd example below, but i keep getting null errors when trying to detect te collision when writing the rocket and player objects in the health class so that's why I am trying it this way. --> see example below

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    Rocket rocket = GameWorld.Find("rocket") as Rocket;

    foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
    {
        SpriteGameObject h = obj as SpriteGameObject;
        if (rocket.CollidesWith(player))
        {
            this.Remove(h);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. Because rocket or player is null.

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    //Rocket rocket = GameWorld.Find("rocket") as Rocket;

    foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
    {
        SpriteGameObject h = obj as SpriteGameObject;
        if (player.Position.X > 200)
        {
            this.Remove(h);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This does remove the health when the player moves past 200 pixels..

I can't figure out a way to get this health bar to work..

This is some more information that might be usefull:

```
class Health : GameObjectList

public Health(int layer = 3, string id = "") : base(layer, id) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i+=85)
        if(i % 85 == 0)
        {
            SpriteGameObject health = new SpriteGameObject("Sprites/spr_health", 3);
            health.Position = new Vector2(120 + i, 15);
            this.Add(health);
        }
}
```

..

```
class Rocket : AnimatedGameObject
```

..

```
partial class Player : AnimatedGameObject
```

Comment: I can't really make out what the question is here.  You said that you're trying to get the health to remove from the bar - are you trying to reduce the figure, or remove the bar?  Are you getting a specific error that you don't understand?

Comment: I'm trying to reove 1 SpriteGameObject health at a time, because 3 of those make up the health bar

Comment: Remove*. I'm trying to remove 1 health out of 3 when the player touches a rocket.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, you are setting up `health`, but referencing gameObjects.  You are not adding health to gameObjects:

```
Health health = new Health(3, "Sprites/spr_health");

if (this.CollidesWith(player) && this.Visible)
    foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
    {
        SpriteGameObject h = obj as SpriteGameObject;
        {
            gameObjects.Remove(h);
        }
    }
```

In the second example, you say that rocket, or player are null.  You haven't included the code where you add them, but since you are using the following construct:

```
Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
```

If the `.Find` function fails, then `player` will be null.

Finally, you say the following code doesn't remove the health when the player passes 200px:

```
 SpriteGameObject h = obj as SpriteGameObject;
 if (player.Position.X > 200)
 {
     this.Remove(h);
     return;
 }
```

You are not searching or checking for the `Health` object at any point.

Comment: Thanks! but at the last bit, that bit of code DOES remove the health when the player passes 200px

Comment: Yes - that's what your code says: if (player.Position.X > 200)